# How can I fit cubic spline method for time series data?

Tags: r, smoothing

I have a longitudinal data record for each unique ID (total of 11,000). I want to smooth Wt. using time (total of 335 unique time point) as a smoothing variable for each unique ID ($1).

The data looks like this

```
ID Wt. Time
10 450 1
10 460 2
10 486 3
10 490 5
100 459 1
100 500 2
100 540 4
100 500 5 
100 490 6
101 370 1
101 380 2
101 390 3
101 400 4
101 375 5
```

I have tried the following code in R but it gives me an error message

```
> model<- Wt ~ s(Time, bs = 'cr', k = 300) + s(ID, bs = 're')
> fit <- bam(model, data = smothweight, family = "gaussian", discrete = TRUE, nthreads = 2)
Error in rep(0, pt^2) : invalid 'times' argument
```

Could you give me some suggestions?

Comment: I see `Wt.` in the data snippet but `Wt` in the formula as response. If that isn't it, try writing the formula inline in the function call, rather than via an object; does problem persist?